# Sprite fade isn't working with CSS

Tags: css, sprite, fade

I am creating a logo fade so on hover the colour of the logo fades from white to blue. The image file is 289px x 165px which is the the size of both logos in one image, sitting directly beneath the other.

I have used this template in other websites but for some reason it isnt working this time. I cant post the actual logo because of reputation.

```
<div id="logo"> <a href="#home"> <span> </span> </a> </div>

#logo a {
display:inline-block;
height: 298px;
width:165px;
background-image: url(../images/logo-sprite.jpg);
float:left;
```

}

```
#logo span{ 
display: inline-block;
height: 298px;
width:165px;
background-image: url(../images/logo-sprite.jpg);
background-position: 0 298px;
-webkit-transition:opacity background-position 1s ease;
-moz-transition:opacity background-position 1s ease;
-o-transition:opacity background-position 1s ease;
transition: background-position 1s ease;
```

}

```
#logo span:hover{
opacity: 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You currently adding transitions for opacity changes. So to add transitions for background images you need to add this :

```
-webkit-transition:background-position 1s ease;
-moz-transition:background-position 1s ease;
-o-transition:background-position 1s ease;
transition: background-position 1s ease;
```

**Update** Above answer will indeed show the background image slide. 
To fix that:

Set the position of the background image on `#logo span` instead during the hover event.

**Change this:**

```
background-position: 0 0;
```

**To this:**

```
background-position: 0 298px;
```

Then during hover no need to set the background position, it should be only like this :

```
#logo span:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Update**
Remove the background position transition

**From:**

```
-webkit-transition:opacity background-position 1s ease;
-moz-transition:opacity background-position 1s ease;
-o-transition:opacity background-position 1s ease;
transition: background-position 1s ease;
```

**To:**

```
-webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease;
-moz-transition:opacity 1s ease;
-o-transition:opacity 1s ease;
transition: opacity 1s ease;
```

[Working sample code](http://plnkr.co/edit/YqBhMI5WXsCvtMkXyn4i?p=preview)

Comment: Ive added that and its now making a downwards roll over effect, both parts of the sprite are always visible

Comment: @amyOakes with the limited code shown I assume you already handled hiding the default background image during hover

Comment: the code i have shown is all that i have used for the whole hover event. I have added the things you have stated, but now the image is just static, its doesnt roll or fade and both parts are still visible. Apologies if im being thick.

Comment: i have updated the question with the code you have told me to change.

Comment: @AmyOakes how does it looks now? Did it achieve what you wanted?

Comment: Forgot to tell you that my first solution was wrong and you have to revert it. Updated code

Comment: No :( its still just static, i'm more or less back at the original code i have unless i have misunderstood something.

Comment: @AmyOakes ok no problem. I'll leave a link for the code I wrote on my answer above.

Comment: ive directly copied what you have wrote on plunker and just changed the dimensions and still just a static image, thanks you for all your help up to now though. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#logo a {
display:block;
height: 149px;
width:165px;
background-image: url(../images/logo-sprite.jpg);
float:left;
background-position: 0 0;
```

}

```
#logo a:hover {
height: 149px;
width:165px;
background-image: url(../images/logo-sprite.jpg);
float:left;
background-position: 0 -149px;
```

}

```
#logo span{ 
height: 149px;
width:165px;
display:none;
background-image: url(../images/logo-sprite.jpg);
opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
 -o-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
```

}

```
#logo span{
opacity: 1;
```

}

after much tinkering this is code that works for me, the dimensions of the image needed to be halved so on half the sprite would be visible at one time.